# $\gamma^t$ in REINFORCE update (Sutton-Barto RL book Exercise 13.2)

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, proofs, sutton-barto, reinforce

I've struggled with solving exercise 13.2 from [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction Second Edition](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html) :

> Generalize the box on page 199, the policy gradient theorem (13.5),
> the proof of the policy gradient theorem (page 325), and the steps
> leading to the REINFORCE update equation (13.8), so that (13.8) ends
> up with a factor of $\gamma^t$ and thus aligns with the general algorithm given
> in the pseudocode.

Below is my attempt. Please let me know if this is correct or where I've made a mistake (exercise 13.2 was was not in the authors' official solutions when I checked).

**Generalize box on 199**

As explained in the box on 199, include a factor of $\gamma$  in the second term of (9.2):

$$
\eta_\gamma(s) = h(s) + \gamma \sum_{\overline{s}} \eta(\overline{s}) \sum_a \pi(a|\overline{s}) p(s|\overline{s},a)
$$

$$
\mu_\gamma(s) = \frac{\eta_\gamma(s)}{\sum_{s^\prime} \eta(s^\prime)}
$$

I initially thought the definition of $\mu_\gamma(s)$ was

$$
\mu_\gamma(s) = \frac{\eta_\gamma(s)}{\sum_{s^\prime} \eta_\gamma(s^\prime)}
$$

but I could not see how to finish the exercise with this definition. Given that we are assuming a single starting state $s_0$, we can also write $\eta_\gamma(s)$ as:

$$
\eta_\gamma(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \gamma^k Pr(s_0 \rightarrow s, k, \pi)
$$

**Generalize Proof of the Policy Gradient Theorem (episodic case)**

I followed the steps in the proof on page 325 and added discounting.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla v_\pi(s) &= \nabla \bigg[\sum_a \pi(a|s) q_\pi(s,a)\bigg] \text{,} \quad \text{for all} \; s \in \mathcal{S} \\
&= \sum_a \bigg[\nabla \pi(a|s) q_\pi(s,a) + \pi(a|s) \nabla q_\pi(s,a)\bigg] \\
&= \sum_a \bigg[\nabla \pi(a|s) q_\pi(s,a) + \pi(a|s) \nabla \sum_{s^\prime,r} p(s^\prime,r|s,a) (r + \gamma v_\pi(s^\prime))\bigg] \\
&= \sum_a \bigg[\nabla \pi(a|s) q_\pi(s,a) + \gamma \pi(a|s) \sum_{s^\prime} p(s^\prime|s,a) \nabla v_\pi(s^\prime)\bigg] \\
&= \sum_a \bigg[\nabla \pi(a|s) q_\pi(s,a) + \gamma \pi(a|s) \sum_{s^\prime} p(s^\prime|s,a) \sum_{a^\prime} \big[\nabla \pi(a^\prime|s^\prime) q_\pi(s^\prime,a^\prime) + \gamma \pi(a^\prime|s^\prime) \sum_{s^{\prime\prime}} p(s^{\prime\prime}|s^\prime,a^\prime) \nabla v_\pi(s^{\prime\prime})\big]\bigg] \\
&= \sum_{x \in \mathcal{S}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \gamma^k Pr(s \rightarrow x, k, \pi) \sum_a \nabla \pi(a|x) q_\pi(x,a)
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla J(\theta) &= \nabla v_\pi(s_0) \\
&= \sum_s \bigg(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \gamma^k Pr(s_0 \rightarrow s, k, \pi)\bigg) \sum_a \nabla \pi(a|s) q_\pi(s,a) \\
&= \sum_s \eta_\gamma(s) \sum_a \nabla \pi(a|s) q_\pi(s,a) \\
&= \sum_{s^\prime} \eta(s^\prime) \sum_s \frac{\eta_\gamma(s)}{\sum_{s^\prime} \eta(s^\prime)} \sum_a \nabla \pi(a|s) q_\pi(s,a) \\
&= \sum_{s^\prime} \eta_\gamma(s^\prime) \sum_s \mu_\gamma(s) \sum_a \nabla \pi(a|s) q_\pi(s,a) \\
&\propto \sum_s \mu_\gamma(s) \sum_a \nabla \pi(a|s) q_\pi(s,a)
\end{aligned}
$$

**Steps leading to the REINFORCE update equation (13.8)**

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla J(\boldsymbol{\theta}) &\propto \sum_s \mu_\gamma(s) \sum_a q_\pi(s,a,\boldsymbol{\theta}) \nabla \pi(a|s) \\
&= \mathbb{E}_\pi\bigg[\gamma^t \sum_a \pi(a|S_t,\boldsymbol{\theta}) q_\pi(S_t,a) \frac{\nabla \pi(a|S_t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\pi(a|S_t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}\bigg] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_\pi\bigg[\gamma^t q_\pi(S_t,A_t) \frac{\nabla \pi(A_t|S_t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\pi(A_t|S_t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}\bigg] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_\pi\bigg[\gamma^t G_t \frac{\nabla \pi(A_t|S_t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\pi(A_t|S_t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}\bigg]
\end{aligned}
$$

Discounted REINFORCE update:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t+1} &\overset{.}{=} \boldsymbol{\theta}_t + \alpha \gamma^t G_t \frac{\nabla \pi(A_t|S_t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\pi(A_t|S_t,\boldsymbol{\theta})} \\
&= \boldsymbol{\theta}_t + \alpha \gamma^t G_t \nabla \ln\pi(A_t|S_t,\boldsymbol{\theta})
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand why the $\gamma^t$ appears when you write the gradient with an expectation. Could you elaborate ? thank you

I agree with you with all the things up to that point

EDIT : to try to answer my own question, I would say that it is important to clarify what the expectation is based on :

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_s \mu_\pi(s) \sum\limits_a q_\pi(s,a) \nabla_\theta \pi(a|s) &= \mathbb{E}_{s \sim \mu_\pi} \big[ \sum\limits_a q_\pi(s,a) \nabla_\theta \log \pi(a|s)\big]\\
&= \mathbb{E_\pi} \big[\gamma^t \sum\limits_a q_\pi(S_t,a) \nabla_\theta \log \pi(a|S_t) \big]
\end{align}

in the first, we use the on-policy undiscounted state distribution, which is not exactly the same as the discounted state distribution, as my understanding of it.
See : https://proceedings.mlr.press/v202/che23a/che23a.pdf

Comment: With $\mathbb{E}_\pi$ I meant the on-policy undiscounted expectation. Since $\mu_\gamma$ is the discounted distribution, I believe we are left with a factor of $\gamma^t$ when rewriting as $\mathbb{E}_\pi$. However, this part is what I was (and still is) the most unsure about.

Comment: So yes I agree with what you've done, but like you I'm not 100% sure. As pointed out in the paper linked and in https://towardsdatascience.com/why-there-is-a-problem-with-the-policy-gradient-theorem-in-deep-reinforcement-learning-958d845218f1, I think it's something a lot of people overlook